# Problem ( Xamarin Visual Studio ) Guest isn't online after 7 second

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator

Hi i get this error when i try to Play and run the emulator
[image]

It show an screen from a previews project and don't show the Current project
I have try to 
Rebuild , Clean build , Build and nothing works
It works when i run it on a phone

I tryed an old emulator i had and it works just a Androis6 
the others like 8 and 8.1 dosent work just give the same problem.
Why is this?

Comment: Try to open the `Xamarin Android SDK Manager` in your IDE by going to `Tools` > `Android` > `SDK Manager`. Update the `Android SDK Tools` and `Android Emulator` to the latest Version. Also you can open `Android Device Manager` to stop the emulator and start the emulator in advance when you want to use an emulator.